# Error parsing wsdl - The sytem cannot find the path specified

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

My ***wsdl*** is at location `http://localhost:9999/ws/hello?wsdl`.
I am using ***wsimport*** tool to parse the published wsdl file, and generate necessary ***client files (stub)*** to access the published web service.

I am unable to parse this wsdl,
  [image]

How can I resolve this?

***HelloWorld.java*** is the ***interface*** and it's ***implementation*** is ***HelloWorldImpl.java***
Both of them resides in the below directory,

```
C:\Users\ANSARI\Desktop\Lexicon\WorkSpaceLuna\WebServices\RPCStyle\src\com\farhan\ws
```

***wsdl file:***
[image]

Comment: Do you see a proper WSDL in browser for this URL : http://localhost:9999/ws/hello?wsdl  and if possible could you post it here?

Comment: @K139: I do see the proper wsdl. Posting it here...

Comment: Seems you don't have permissioin to write in \bin folder. Try to execute the wsimport from a different folder where you have write permission. And also keep the JAVA_HOME\bin folder in your path.

Comment: @K139: I am able to create a folder inside bin easily.

Comment: Perhaps your getting problems because your working directory is under the `Program Files` folder which has whitespace characters in the path. You could try running the command from some other folder and adding quotes around the path, e.g. `cd C:\temp` `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\wsimport" -keep http://localhost:9999/ws/hello?wsdl`

Comment: @Mick Mnemonic: Thank you so so much. It solved the problem for me. Kindly raise this comment as an answer, then I will mark it as accepted. Please share your thoughts why it couldn't be resolved when there are whitespaces characters in the path.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are executing the `wsimport` command from a working directory whose path contains white space characters (`Program Files`). This is a likely source of problems for the code generation (JAXB binding objects, WS stubs) part of `wsimport`.

When output folders for generated files are not explicitly specified using the `-d` or `-s` [options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html#Syntax), the current working directory will be used as the default value. It seems like `wsimport` does not surround the directory parameter in quotes when it internally invokes JAX-WS / JAXB code-generation tools.

To fix the problem, you can run the command from a directory that does not have whitespace in the path. You also need to surround the path to `wsimport` with quotes when calling the command:

```
cd C:\temp
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\wsimport" -keep http://localhost:9999/ws/hello?wsdl
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.